# Ocaml function parsing list of lists

Tags: list, parsing, ocaml, ml

I am trying to build a function in Ocaml which parses a list of lists, eg from [[0;1];[3;4;8]] to [0;1;3;4;8]. I tried to do something like:

```
#let rec parse listoflists= 
   match listoflists with 
 [[]]->[]
|[h::t]->h::parse [t];;
```

but it doesn't work... I also need an explanation, because I don't understand how the lists of lists actually work...

I don't have to use the Ocaml library functions.

Comment: *I don't have to use the Ocaml library functions.* But can you? You're describing `List.concat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can understand a list, then I claim you already know about lists of lists. This is the beauty of recursion.

The only real difficulty (as I see it) is keeping track of which list you're talking about. Your code needs to work with the list of lists itself, which consists of one list (call it `h`) followed by some other lists. It also needs to work with the list h, which consists of some element (call it `hh`) followed by some other elements.

It seems to me there are three interesting cases: (a) the list of lists is empty; (b) the first element of the list of lists `h` is empty (c) neither the list of lists nor `h` is empty.

You are not handling all three of these cases. That's one way to see that your code probably wouldn't work.

Here is a `match` that matches the three cases, which might help a little:

```
match listoflists with
| [] -> ...              (* List of lists is empty *)
| [] :: t -> ...         (* First list h is empty *)
| (hh :: ht) :: t -> ... (* Neither is empty *)
```